# How to I style a UIToolbar to look like the standard iPhone camera toolbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The iPhone camera toolbar is gray and has a slight gradient. I believe I could achieve the same look by setting the tintColor and/or translucency of the toolbar.

Any idea how I could make my toolbar look exactly like the camera one?

This isn't quite right... too dark:

```
UIToolbar *tb = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
tb.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Comment: I think the first answer should be accepted

Answer (score 6):

try

```
tb.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

or

```
tb.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does setting the toolbar's barStyle property to UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent give you the effect you want?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me on iOS 7.1

```
tb.barStyle=-1;
tb.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
```